# What is the meaning of Rig Vedic 'Jishnu' in scripture?

Tags: scripture, rig-veda, translation-request

In  RV.7.35 Rishi Vashist MaitraVaruni  describes various gods, things and places which were auspicious. Here in the hymn 5 we find a term  jishnu -

> sham no rajsaspatirstu jishnu

T.H.Griffith translates this as -

> gracious the Lord victorious of the region.

But, I have found this term Jishnu  in GujarAti Dictionary as an another name of Lord Indra. Now I want to know - do other other scriptures validate or contradict the meaning found in GujarAti Dictionary?

Comment: The word Jishnu appears many times in the Vishnu-sahasranama-stotra ('vishnum jishnum mahavishnum...' and also 'avikaaraya shuddhaaya...vishnave sarva-jishnave' etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Mantra you quoted in the question is  from [**Rig-Veda**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv07035.htm) -Mandala 7 - Sukta 35  -  The Rishi of this sukta is Vaisihtha MaitraVaruni . And Devata is Vishwadevas i.e. Various gods.  These are Mantras for peace and bliss.

> शं नो द्यावापृथिवी    पूर्वहूतौ  शमन्तरिक्षं दृशये नो  अस्तु |
>  शं न
>   ओषधीर्वनिनो भवन्तु शं नो रजसस्पतिरस्तु **जिष्णु:** ||Rig-Veda
>   7.35.5||
>
> Early invoked, may Heaven and Earth be friendly, and Air's mid-region
>   good for us to look on. To us may Herbs and Forest-Trees be gracious,
>   gracious the **Lord Victorious of the region.**

The meaning of the word "Jishnu" translated by various authors are somewhat same .Jishnu (जिष्णु) = Victorious [**Lokpal or Lok Pati**](https://archive.org/stream/RigVedaSubodhBhasya4/%E0%A4%8B%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%A6%20%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AC%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A7%20%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%20rig%20veda%20subodh%20bhasya%20%20%284%29#page/n319)  , Lord Victorious of the region, [**Victorious lord of the world**](https://archive.org/stream/RigVedaSanhitaByHHWilsonVol4/Rig%20Veda%20Sanhita%20by%20H%20H%20Wilson%20Vol%204#page/n181)  etc.

---

Now lets see what other scriptures like Mahabharata and Puranas are saying about this word.

Starting from Mahabharata , the word Jishnu is used here for Arjuna. i.e. Jishnu is one of the ten names of Arjuna. Here in [**Virata Parva - Gau haran parva**](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-fourth-book/d/doc116961.html) - Chapter 44 -Arjuna himself is telling his name Jishnu to uttara.

> अहं दुरापो दुर्धर्षो दमन: पाकशासनि: |
>  तेन देवमनुष्येषु
>   **जिष्णुर्नामास्मी** विश्रुत : ||21||
>
> I am known among human beings and celestials by the name of Jishnu,
>   because I am unapproachable and incapable of being kept down, and a
>   tamer of adversaries and son of the slayer of Paka.

Here Arjuna is saying that he is son of Indra , but the name is of Arjuna although mention of Indra.

---

In puranas like [**Garuda Purana**](http://hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/garud-puran/garuda-vol-2/chapter-01/topic-14) - Achar Kanda - Chapter 31 - Description of another form of Vishnu worship , the name Jishnu is used fro Lord Vishnu as one of his name uttered during worship.

> **जिष्णवे** सर्वदेवानां सर्वगाय महात्मने ||
>  ब्रह्मेन्द्ररूद्रवन्द्याय
>   सर्वेशाय नमोनम: ||27||
>
> salutation unto the great Jishnu the lord of all gods and present
>   everywhere. Salutation again and again unto the lord of all adored of
>   Brahma , Rudra and Indra.

---

In [**Vayu Purana**](http://hinduscriptures.in/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/vayu-mahapurana/text-with-translation/vol-i/chapter-25/topic-1) - Chapter -25 - "Description of the obtainment of a boon from Shankara of Vishnu.  " - Its said that Lord Vishnu (probably Maha Vishnu) created two of his forms , same as brothers one is Vishnu and another is "Jishnu" to protect Brahma  from demons Madhu and Kaitabha.

> गते तस्मिन्स्ततोSनन्त उद्गिर्य भ्रातरौ मुखात |
>   **विष्णुं जिष्णुं** च प्रोवाच ब्रह्माण भिरक्षताम|
>  मधुकैटभयोर्ज्ञ्नात्वा तयोरागमनं पुनः ||[**Vayu Purana 25.37**](https://archive.org/stream/VayuPuranaG.V.TagarePart1/Vayu%20Purana%20-%20G.V.Tagare%20-%20Part%201#page/n227) ||
>
> When Brahma had gone , Lord Vishnu created two brothers - Vishnu and
>   Jishnu out of his mouth and instructed them - Both of you should
>   protect Brahma having known the arrival of Madhu and Kaitabha .

So again we can here see the association of the name Jishnu to Vishnu. And Vishnu created two brothers from his mouth (probably Nara-Narayana) .

---

So as you required the Puranas and Mahabharata meaning of word Jishnu  is different than   the meaning found in GujarAti Dictionary you have seen . Although one of the name of the Indra is jishnu , but the word is also used for Vishnu and Arjuna.

---

Here are the various meaning of the word from [**spokensanskrit**](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=jishnu&direct=au)  .

Comment: Thanks for bringing two references, with divergent meaning, I find the reference from Maha Bharata more in proximity of Rig Veda than that of Garud  Purana. But I am not satisfied with the translation. So I would like to elaborate your answer.

Comment: I remember  that word occurs in वैदिक राष्ट्रगीत: "ॐ आ ब्रह्मन् ब्राह्मणो ब्रह्मवर्चसी जायताम् ।

अास्मिन राष्ट्रे राजन्य: इषव्य: शूरो महारथो जायताम् ।

दोग्ध्री धेनु: वोढा ऽनडवान् आशु: सप्ति:

पुरन्ध्रि: योषा **जिष्णू** रथेष्ठा:

सभेयो युवास्य यजमानस्य वीरो जायताम् ।

निकामे निकामे न: पर्जन्यो वर्षतु

फलवत्यो न ओषधय: पच्यन्तां

योगक्षेमो न: कल्पताम् ।। - शुक्ल यजु. २२.२२

Comment: @Pandya - Yes , that's great find. Unfortunately the two commentaries on that mantra aren't explaining the  detail meaning of word and the the mantra is dedicated to Brahman. Devata of that mantra is Lingokta , so is not associated with Indra.

Comment: @B.N.Bhaskar Ok , I will try to find the meaning of the word  as you required. BTW i have just updated answer with one more ref. from Vayu purana. Even  seems like the word Jishnu  also is  use for Sun god.